# Where can I find documentation of android maps.google.com intent URI

Tags: android, google-maps

I found some SO questions that were useful, but I need a complete reference guide for this api and its url paramters.

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon)

Edited

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="
                            + journey.getSourceGPSX() + ","
                            + journey.getSourceGPSY() + "&daddr="
                            + journey.getDestinationGPSX() + ","
                            + journey.getDestinationGPSY()));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'd really class it as an API as such, you're just referencing a URI. I don't think there's much else you can pass in the way of query parameters to that URI other than the various formats of source and destination that Google supports everywhere. For example this post mentions a few different formats:

[is there a way to pass arguments to google map's get directions functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217068/is-there-a-way-to-pass-arguments-to-google-maps-get-directions-functionality)

But apart from that I don't think you're missing any 'hidden' ones.

Comment: `https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=new+york&daddr=baltimore&saddr=harrisburg&daddr=ohio` how to you get this working ? multiple routes ?

Comment: I don't think multiple routes are possible. But I'm not 100% sure of that so it might be worth seeing if you can find any examples using multiple destinations. Just to clarify I mean using a simple web link, if you use the full API as in the other answer it's a different story.

Comment: Nope, not supported. Damn!! I am trying to avoid writing a million lines of code to drawlines from a json response. Painful and buggy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a full api reference here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/

Android is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

There is also a bunch of webservices you might find helpful here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

Is that what you are looking for?