# How do I embed a php variable into an html href link?

Tags: php, embed, query-string, href

Requirement:
Read rows from a mysql database, where one column contains an address and a city, make the resulting address into a link to google maps, by passing the address for the location only as described in the following link:
[is there a way to pass arguments to google map's get directions functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217068/)
php code shippet
    
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo''.$row['DAYTIME'].''.$row['MEETINGNAME'].'    '.'['.$row['ADDRESSCITY'].'](http://maps.google.com/?q=)'.''.$row['BLDGNAME'].'';
    }
    ?>
The above block of code sucefully creates a link to maps.google.com BUT
I want to put $row['ADDRESSCITY'] between the "http://maps.google.com/?q=
and the closing "
I tried this:

```
'<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q='.$row['ADDRESSCITY'].'/a'">'
```

and no results are displayed, and no error message either.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to remove the quote " just after `<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=`

Answer (score 0):

Change the url to this.

```
echo'<tr><td>'.$row['DAYTIME'].'</td><td>'.$row['MEETINGNAME'].'</td><td>'.'<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q='.$row['ADDRESSCITY'].'">Google Maps</a>'.'</td><td>'.$row['BLDGNAME'].'</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo'<tr><td>'.$row['DAYTIME'].'</td><td>'.$row['MEETINGNAME'].'</td><td>'.'<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q="'.$row['ADDRESSCITY'].'"></a></td><td>'.$row['BLDGNAME'].'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Requirement: Must open the above link in a new window. Here is what I tried, but it did not open a new window or tab (I don't care which) - those pesky single and double quotes!

Comment: echo'<tr><td>'.$row['DAYTIME'].'</td><td>'.$row['MEETINGNAME'].'</td><td>'.'<a href="https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr='.$row['ADDRESSCITY'].' target="_blank".'">'.$row['ADDRESSCITY'].'</a>'.'</td><td>'.$row['BLDGNAME'].'</td></tr>';